# Import react-native libraries in Ionic-React Project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework, react-native-web, ionic-react

I just trying to work with [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) in my **ionic react** project and  I was able to make it successful with react-native-web.  But then if I do import like

```
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
```

it says

> cannot find module react-native.

how can i solve this?

[image]

Comment: web not support `react-native` module

Comment: It's a miracle even being able to install and use react-native-svg. The problem is, react-native is completely something else from ionic. I don't think you can combine react-native with ionic, probably no one has tried. If you want to use react-native, just use react-native. If you want to use ionic, just use ionic. react-native-svg probably did install react-native, but it is just it's dependency right now. you can try to install it with npm or yarn but i don't think you can even get it work, just as i said earlier. https://ionicframework.com/resources/articles/ionic-react-vs-react-native

Comment: First you need to check what is ionic-react. from my point you misunderstand ionic-react. in ionic-react you can use reactjs coding standard instead of angular in Ionic